# PHP - echo image as jpg not ascii

Tags: php, image, echo

I am trying to echo an image after fopen and fread it, but it shows as ascii code not as image format.

I found an answer:

[Fopen function opens JPEG image as text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25548085/fopen-function-opens-jpeg-image-as-text)

I implemented the header() line in my code but it seems that it try to open my current php file as jpg not the image.

Here is my code:

```
        $filename = $n.".jpg";
        //echo $n.'.jpg'; prints image_name.jpg
        $fp = fopen($filename, "r");
        $data = fread($fp, filesize($filename));

        header('Content-type: image/jpg'); //without the header line I can print the ascii
        echo $data; //I want to print my $data as image format not ascii

        fclose($fp);
```

(I don't know if it does matter but I am using latest version of XAMPP and W7)

Thanks in advance

Comment: This might be a caching issue of your browser. Try to really refresh the page request.

Comment: This code worked without any modifications for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you use fopen, try

```
$fp = fopen($filename, "rb");
```

to enforce binary mode. I'm lazy and use this:

```
$filename = $n.".jpg";
header('Content-type: image/jpg'); //without the header line I can print the ascii
echo file_get_contents($filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

I miss the point why you want to output the image through a script instead of serving it directly, since it is already a jpg image.

Nonetheless maybe you should try instead of echoing the file contents, using fpassthrough that outputs all remaining data on a file pointer

```
$filename = $n.".jpg";
$fp = fopen($filename, "r");

header('Content-type: image/jpg'); //without the header line I can print the ascii

fpassthru($fp)
fclose($fp);
```

You may also call readfile function directly  http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php without having to use fopen